# How to easily get ts type of react-native element prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I found myself doing following a lot lately

```
// MyButton.tsx
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native"

interface Props {
 onPress: () => void
}

//...

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onPress} />
```

Essentially I am making my own "wrapper" components around react native ones and these wrapper components usually take similar props as react native components they wrap. I have to always re-type these props.

I don't want to extend all props of native component, rather expose some very specific ones. It would be awesome to do something like this

```
interface Props = {
  onPress: TouchableWithoutFeedback.onPress
}
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work, but something like this would help a lot with prop safety as I don't define my own type.

Is this achievable somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the type definition, not the class itself. Assuming you have installed `@types/react-native`:

```
import { TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps } from 'react-native'

interface Props {
  onPress: TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps["onPress"] // <-- must be bracket notation
}
```

I think all of their component prop definitions follow the same naming pattern, so `View` would be `ViewProps`, `Text` would be `TextProps` etc

Bracket notation is because dot notation is only valid on namespaces in ts